# Error 302 when communicating java with google-app-engine

Tags: java, android, http, google-app-engine

I'm running a java code for getting info from a google-app-engine web service (testeserjaum.appspot.com), but it always prints `{null=[HTTP/1.1 302 Found], Date=[Wed, 26 Oct 2011 21:02:46 GMT], Content-Length=[0], Location=[https://testeserjaum.appspot.com/], Content-Type=[text/html], Server=[Google Frontend]}` on the first System.out.println and `null` on the second one.

The funny fact is that, with other google-app-engine web services, the code works perfectly (i tried with testegelfur.appspot.com and it worked).

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
           URL url = new URL("http://testeserjaum.appspot.com/");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           System.out.println(urlConnection.getHeaderFields());
           try {
             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
             System.out.println(buff.readLine());
           }finally{
             urlConnection.disconnect();
           }

    }
}
```

And, I don't know if it helps, but here's a python equivalent that actually works. I can't use it because I plan to use this software on an android application, and I have a large amount of the software done, so this have to be done in java.

```
import urllib2
import base64

req = urllib2.Request('http://testeserjaum.appspot.com/')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
#base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' %('user', 'pass'))
#print base64string
#req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" %base64string)
lol = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print lol.read()
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, rather than a pastebin. Pastebins have a tendency to go away, and it makes the question harder to read, too. I've edited your question to add the code inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP 302 is a redirect, not an error. That's why it's called *Found*.

Specifically, it tells the client to fetch `https://testeserjaum.appspot.com/` instead of `http://testeserjaum.appspot.com/`.

If you don't want to deal with the redirect, just access `https://testeserjaum.appspot.com/` directly.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error.  It's a temporary redirect, which you can follow.  Some libraries always follow redirects for you; some never do.  Others leave it up to you.  If the library doesn't, you can do so in user code.

However, Java provides the convenient [`setFollowRedirects`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) for just this purpose.

Comment: I know that, any idea of why is this happening and how to fix it? Because it don't happen on other google-app-engine web-services neither on other common sites (neither on the python code).

Comment: Which of these services (testeserjaum, testegelfur, etc. do you have the source to)?  Do you know why/if they redirect?  Could they be using user-agent sniffing to detect HttpUrlConnection? EDIT: It seems that one of them is set to force to HTTPS.  It's happening in the browser, so I don't think it's sniffing.  It probably happens in Python automatically, but you didn't notice.